# bulk data update from MSSQL vis kafka connector to elasticsearch with nested types is failing

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

MSSQL value : column name=prop --> value= 100 and column name=role --> value= [{"role":"actor"},{"role":"director"}]
NOTE: the column:role is saved in json format.

read from kafka topic :

```
{
   "schema":{
      "type":"struct",
      "fields":[
         {
            "type":"int32",
            "optional":false,
            "field":"prop"
         },
         {
            "type":"string",
            "optional":true,
            "field":"roles"
         }
 ],
      "optional":false
   },
   "payload":{ "prop":100, "roles":"[{"role":"actor"},{"role":"director"}]"}
```

**failing with the reason :**

```
Error was [{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"object mapping for [roles] tried to parse field [roles] as object, but found a concrete value"}
```

*Reason for failing is that the connector is not able to create schema as array for roles*

The above input message is created by confluent JdbcSourceConnector and the sink connector used is confluent ElasticsearchSinkConnector

**Configuration details :**

## sink config:

```
name=prop-test
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
connection.url=<elasticseach url>

tasks.max=1

topics=test_prop
type.name=prop

#transforms=InsertKey, ExtractId

transforms.InsertKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
transforms.InsertKey.fields=prop

transforms.ExtractId.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
transforms.ExtractId.field=prop
```

## Source config:

```
name=test_prop_source
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver://*.*.*.*:1433;instance=databaseName=test;
connection.user=*****
connection.password=*****
query=EXEC <store proc>
mode=bulk
batch.max.rows=2000000
topic.prefix=test_prop
transforms=createKey,extractInt
transforms.createKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
transforms.createKey.fields=prop

transforms.extractInt.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
transforms.extractInt.field=prop
```

## connect-standalone.properties :

```
    bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

    key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

    key.converter.schemas.enable=true
    value.converter.schemas.enable=true
```

need to understand how explicitly i can make the schema as ARRAY for roles and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the jdbc Source connector will always sees columnname as fieldname and columnvalue as value. This conversion from string to array is not possible with the existing jdbc source connector support, it has to be a custom transformation or custom plugin to enable it.

The best option available for getting the data transferred from the MSSQL and getting it inserted into the Elastic Search is by using logstash. It has rich filter plugins which can enable the data from MSSQL to flow in any desired format and to any desired JSON output environment ( logstash/kafka topic )

Flow : MSSQL --> logstash --> Kakfa Topic  --> Kafka Elastic sink connector --> Elastic Search